# IF statement to show if ALL cells in a row have the same value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I want to write a formula in Excel to determine if EVERY cell in a row has the same value.  There are five cells, for example: C2:G2 that I need to filter out only the ones with the same value, so if only one out of the five cells has it then it's fine, but if every single cell has the same value I need to take it out.  So far the only formula I have been able to write just puts `TRUE` if the value is in any cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:G2,C2)=5
```

Comment: I literally figured it out when you posted this, even though it was taking me an hour before lol.  But this is the answer.  Thank you!